# SSRS Dynamic Shared Data Source

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2008

I have an ASP.Net Web site that displays various SSRS reports using the Microsoft Report Viewer Control. I need to be able to specify a data source at runtime. It seems like I should be able to just specify the name of a "shared" data source when I render the report, but I sure can't find a way to do that. The only thing I've found so far that works is to use an "embedded" data source. I'm not real crazy about that, but if that's my only option it will have to do.

Anybody know how to specify a shared data source at runtime?

Comment: Why do you need that ? What is the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, but if there is already a custom app accessing SSRS reports this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355461/Dynamically-Pointing-to-Shared-Data-Sources-on-SQL) might be a good solution.