# SSRS - Bulk update datasources from dev to prod

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We've been developing reports in a dev environment for a few months and we're ready for a data migration and to point these reports to a new location.

What I need to do is change the data source for all of these reports without having to go to each report, change the data source, and re-deploy the reports.

I'm thinking I could be able to just change the current data source from the SSRS portal to point to the new location, but I would still need to touch each report and update them in source control.

I also came across a page for the RS.exe utility [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rs-exe-utility-ssrs?view=sql-server-2016). Not sure if that is going to do what I'm looking for.

Is there a best practice for this or is touching each report the only way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you update the datasource directly from the server to point to the new location, this will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid manually configuring individual Data Sources, you will either have to use an existing 3rd party tool or create one yourself that wraps the reporting services api.

I have two suggestions that might not be useful now, since you are ready to deploy, however, they might prove useful in future report development.

1. Use [Shared Data Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/create-modify-and-delete-shared-data-sources-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017). In your reports, configure each Data Set to point to one Shared Data Source. This would allow you to configure the connection information once per instance.
2. Use a [dynamic connection string expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065148/dynamically-set-the-data-source-for-ssrs-reports-without-unattended-execution-ac/24073346#24073346) for your report Data Source configuration.

Comment: You are right, I'm too in the weeds. We already utilize the Shared Data Sources and dynamic connections for all solutions except this one :) Looks like I'm going to have to manually touch each report and deploy. Appreciate the response