# how to read the data source configuration from an external file in Power BI report builder

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, powerbi-paginated-reports

We have developed a paginated report in Power BI report builder. In the paginated report, we have created a data source and pointed it to a dataset in Power BI.

Now we have a requirement to point the report dynamically to different datasets depending upon the workspace where the paginated report is published. All the datasets have the same structure but different data depending on the workspace where the datasets reside.

One option could be the possibility to check if the dataset path can be read from a file. Another option would be to use a relative path where the file reads the same name dataset from the workspace where the painted report is published.

However, I have not seen any such possibility. I would appreciate if someone knows how this can be achieved.

Regards
Syed

Comment: The datasource can be parameterised, take look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065148/dynamically-set-the-data-source-for-ssrs-reports-without-unattended-execution-ac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the .rdl file before deployment.  [RDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/report-definition-language-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16) is .XML and fully documented, so this should be easy.

Or by calling the [Update Datasources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/update-datasources-in-group) REST API after deployment.